# Delete last line always starting with 'TRAILER' from a text file in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, script

I want to remove the last line from a text file using a windows batch script. the last line will always be like 'TRAILER|'. How can i achieve that. My .txt file looks like :

1220|6963|TRUCK|5760|

1221|6964|TRUCK|1440|

1220|6965|TRUCK|2880|

1221|6966|TRUCK|2880|

1221|6967|TRUCK|2880|

TRAILER|5|

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345964/deleting-last-n-lines-from-file-using-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried in your way by writing :
>
> ```
> findstr /v TRAILER %SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt > %IN_DIR%\loc.txt
> ```
>
> Here `%SFTP_INDIR% = D:\Batch\Batch_FWK\SFTP\inbox.`
>
> Output file loc.txt does not contain last record `TRAILER|5|` now, but
>   it printed each record like this in the output file:
>
> ```
> D:\Batch\Batch_FWK\SFTP\inbox\Location.20150528060210.txt:1220|6963|TRUCK|5760|
> ```

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/926328/337631) by [Romeo Ninov](https://superuser.com/users/409497/romeo-ninov)

```
findstr /v TRAILER filename >newfilename
```

works as you would like **only** when removing the last line from a **single** file.

This is because:

> If more than one file is searched, the results will be prefixed with
>   the filename where the text was found. The file name is not printed if
>   the request was explicitly for a single file, or if searching piped
>   input or redirected input.

To get round this limitation you can use a `for` command to process multiple single files and output the results to one file.

Try the following command in a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b "%SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt"') do findstr /v TRAILER %%a >> %IN_DIR%\loc.txt
```

When running from a command line replace `%%` with `%`.

---

Source [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)